# Conditional styling not being applied to a div

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, primevue

I'm trying to map an array of cards wrapped in a div but I want the first, second, second to last, and the last of these divs to cause a new line / take the entire row. I'm using Vue3 and the PrimeVue component library.

```
<div class="row" v-for="(task, index) in tasks" :class="{ 
    'p-col-12 dp-block': index === 0,
    'p-col-12 dp-block': index === 1,
    'p-col-12': index == tasks.length-2,
    'p-col-12': index === tasks.length-1,
     }" :key="task">
        <Card style="width: 25em; vertical-align: middle;">
            // card content
        </Card>
</div>
```

In the code above I'm checking the index of each item in my array and if that item has an index of 0, 1, tasks.length-1 or tasks.length-2 it should have the "p-col-12" class applied to it.

In my case the second to last element does not have that class applied to it.

My conditional styling code appears to be correct but I would love to get an opinion from more experienced people.

Comment: Hello, I would make a method that returns the appropriate classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a method for this

```
methods: {
  getStyleClasses() {
    let className = ''
    if (
      this.index === this.tasks.length - 2 ||
      this.index === this.tasks.length - 1
    )
      className = className.concat(' p-col-12')
    if (this.index === 0 || this.index === 1)
      className = className.concat(' dp-block')
    return className
  },
},
```

And use it like so

```
<div
  class="row"
  v-for="(task, index) in tasks"
  :class="getStyleClasses()"
  :key="task"
>
  <Card style="width: 25em; vertical-align: middle;">
        // card content
  </Card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could target those elements using CSS only, via `:nth-child` and `:nth-last-child` and apply the style to make the elements `100%` wide, so you wouldn't need to introduce unnecessary logic.

E.g.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 10px;  
}

div {
  background: yellowgreen;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

div:is(:nth-child(1), 
       :nth-child(2), 
       :nth-last-child(1), 
       :nth-last-child(2)) {
   flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">1</div>
  <div class="row">2</div>
  <div class="row">3</div>
  <div class="row">4</div>
  <div class="row">5</div>
  <div class="row">6</div>
  <div class="row">7</div>
  <div class="row">8</div>
  <div class="row">9</div>
</section>
```